# AWS GitHub identity provider configuration to allow granular access for different repositories

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, openid-connect

I have configured an identity provider for GitHub in my AWS account to allow authentication from my actions.

Is it possible to have specific policies for specific repositories?

I currently have a role with a trust policy that looks like this.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "GitHubActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:my-org/my-repo:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have given it an IAM policy which looks like this.

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": ""
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:repository/test-image",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```